# Как исправить различия в верстке таблиц в современных браузерах?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

1. Google Chrome Версия 34.0.1847.131 m
   [image: Google Chrome]
2. Mozilla Firefox Версия 29.0
   [image: Mozilla Firefox]
3. Opera Версия 20.0.1387.91
   [image: Opera]
4. Internet Explorer Версия 10.0.9200.16540
   [image: Internet Explorer]

Как исправить различия в верстке таблиц в современных браузерах? и что можно сделать с Internet Explorer, чтобы он нормально отображал сайт?

Comment: Таблицами уже не верстают!

Верстайте div'ами.

Comment: Я не верстаю таблицами! Мне нужно сверстать ТАБЛИЦУ, а она отображается по-разному в разных браузерах... Как исправить???

Comment: Получается, что только в Файерфоксе все ОК, а в других браузерах не отображается правый border у tbody. В IE 10 вообще ппц, без комментариев. Что делать? Как исправить?

Comment: @eprivalov1, вряд ли среди пользователей сайта есть Кашпировские. Лечение по фотографиям не практикуем. Выложите, пожалуйста, демо-пример на jsFiddle, иллюстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Также, почему-то, ни в одном браузере не срабатывает CSS свойство border-radius для таблицы, углы не становятся скругленными. Почему так происходит?

Comment: border-radius работает только если таблице задано свойство border-collapse: separate;

Comment: @eprivalov1 normalize.css не пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала наверное нужно указать doctype и прописывать полностью свойства (например background-color а не background) также не плохо было создать отдельную таблицу стилей для ие.
Также указать для всех новых тегов html5 свойство display:block а для ие сделать это через js.
также советую проверить сайт на валидность
и если требуется воспользоваться костылями для браузеров